# Why does this line of C++ cause seg fault?

Tags: c++

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};


int main()
{

    ListNode *dummy(0);
    cout << dummy->val << endl;
}
```

It segfaults at dummy->val

And why does this work?

```
ListNode initNode(0);
ListNode *dummy = &initNode;
```

Comment: Because you're deferencing on a null pointer.

Comment: Because you actually dereference a `nullptr`? That's _undefined behaviour_. I'd get up to my wardrobe and inspect if my cat was bearing kittens. But wait, I have no cat :-P ...

Comment: I thought I initialized a ListNode pointer? Why is it null?

Comment: You're initializing it with `0`, i.e. null pointer.

Comment: Why does this work: ListNode initNode(0);
ListNode *dummy = &initNode;

Comment: Because, this time, you're not initializing a pointer to null, then dereferencing.

Comment: @samol _"And why does this work?"_ Because that's something completely different.

Comment: I guess you're confusing the usage of `0`; for the 1st case it's used to initialize the pointer directly and then form a null pointer, for the 2nd case it's used to initialize an object, whose address is used to initialize the pointer.

Comment: This is all the more reason to use `nullptr`

Answer (score 0):

In the first case
`ListNode *dummy(0);`
You are assigning a null value to the object, which is why its crashing.
In the second case you are initializing the address of the object

```
ListNode *dummy = &initNode;
```